# How to put space before and after operators for enhanced readability?

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

I want -

- `variable++;` then `variable ++;`
- `variable1 + variable2` nothing to do
- `variable1 +variable2` then `variable1 + variable2`
- `variable1+ variable2` then `variable1 + variable2`
- `variable1+variable2` then `variable1 + variable2`

similarly for `-,*,/,>=,<=,!=,==`.
And if -

- `variable1 = variable2` then nothing to do
- `variable1 =variable2` then `variable1 = variable2`
- `variable1= variable2` then `variable1 = variable2`
- `variable1=variable2` then `variable1 = variable2`

I try the search regex as `[a-zA-Z]+([-+/*=]|>=|<=|!=|==)` although it is not correct fully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be this:

First change the infix operators:

```
:%s/\v(\w) ?(\+|-|\*|\/|\>\=|\<\=|!\=|\=|\=\=) ?(\w|-)/\1 \2 \3/g
```

N.B. This also handles the `int x=-b` case [mentioned in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15211/how-to-put-space-before-and-after-of-a-operator-for-ehance-readability/15214?noredirect=1#comment26065_15214).

Then the postfix `++`:

```
:%s/\v(\w)\+\+/\1 ++/g
```

Broken down, that first regular expression is:

- `\v`: Turn on "very magic" matching.
- `(\w) ?`: Find a "word character" optionally followed by a space, capturing the word character into a group.
- `(\+|-|\*|\/|\>\=|\<\=|!\=|\=|\=\=)`: Find any of `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `>=`, `<=`, `!=`, `=`, or `==`, capturing it into a second group.
- `_?(\w|-)`: Find another optional space (represented here as an underscore so you can see it!) followed by another word character (or minus symbol), captured into the third group.

We then replace the entire match with the contents of the three groups, separated by spaces:

`\1 \2 \3`

For more info, see `:help regexp`, and specifically:

- `:help \magic`
- `:help \w`
- `:help \?`
- `:help \|`
- `:help \1`

Comment: you can simplify the regex a bit by using `[+*/=]` instead of alternation.. for the postfix --> `:%s/\w\zs++/ &/g`

Comment: @Sundeep How do you specify `<=` in a square-bracket delimited character class? Your solution for the postfix is nicer, but I went with the above for simplicity--because it uses the same regex elements as the previous

Comment: @Rich your infix regex donesn't work for `int x=-b;`. You can also add Sundeep's comment's regex with description as alternation way.

Comment: @helal: To match `int x=-b`, you can add in the `-`: `:%s/\v(\w) ?(\+|\*|\/|\>\=|\<\=|!\=|\=|\=\=) ?(\w|-)/\1 \2 \3/g`

Comment: @Rich another is it doesn't work for `a-b` that should be result as `a - b` but `a=-b` should be as `a = -b` not `a = - b`

Comment: @helal I forgot to include `-` in my original regexp! See my edit, which includes fixes for this and the new case you mentioned above.

Comment: @Rich the character class is only for single character match... `<=` will be part of alternation... for ex: `[+*/=]|\<\=|etc`

Comment: @Rich would you give me a regex that insert space after `;` it there is any character after `;` instead of space.

Comment: @helal Untested: `:%s/\v;([^ ])/; \1/g` or using Sundeep's method: `%s/;\ze[^ ]/; /g`

Comment: Though I know its an old question, any clue how to use the accepted answer inside autocmd?
  `au BufWritePre *.f90 silent! exe "%s/\v(\w) ?(\+|-|\*|\/|\>\=|\<\=|!\=|\=|\=\=) ?(\w|-)/\1 \2 \3/"` is not working

Comment: Though I know its an old question, any clue how to use the accepted answer inside autocmd?
  `au BufWritePre *.f90 silent! exe "%s/\v(\w) ?(\+|-|\*|\/|\>\=|\<\=|!\=|\=|\=\=) ?(\w|-)/\1 \2 \3/"` is not working

Comment: @BaRud I'd guess what's going wrong there is that instead of adding the command itself, you're :executing a string, but the string is wrong because it contains backslashes. Try changing the double quotes to single quotes. (See `:help literal-string` & `:help string`)